# camera following player

Tags: unity

this code is for camera follow player:

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class cameraMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject player;
    private Vector3 pos;
    private Vector3 rot;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        pos = transform.position;
        rot = transform.localRotation;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        transform.position = player.transform.position + pos;
        transform.RotateAround = player.transform.RotateAround + rot;
    }
}
```

camera position work good.

but camera rotation don't work!!
what is the problem?

Comment: Can you ellaborate? What's the issue you're seeing? Does the camera not rotate ate all, does it rotate but not where you expect? If you can upload an image of what you're seeing, that will also be helpful

Comment: @hobnob it doesn't work.  Isn't that enough information to solve this conundrum?

Comment: @Jon You can usually get better answers if you describe the way it isn't working. A total lack of rotation would point to one problem, and rotation that never stops would indicate another. "It doesn't work" may not be enough information in all cases, particularly when someone asks for clarification.

Comment: rotation store in unity as Quaternion why do you try it by **Vector3 rot;** you can use transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler( Vector 3);

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with the way you're trying to set the rotation. transform.RotateAround is a function, not a variable. You can't set transform.RotateAround equal to something else.

The easiest way to get the camera to follow the player would be to make the camera a child of the player in the editor. You wouldn't have to use any scripting at all, and the camera would always follow the player, including rotation.

If you do want to have the camera follow via scripting, you should try
transform.rotation = player.transform.rotation + Quaternion.Euler(rot). However, the best way really would be to make the camera a child of the player.